# Using Case Statement in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have been learning SQL,and I was trying to learn about the CASE on Oracle LiveSQL:

This is the query I am trying to use:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME, CASE
WHEN SALARY>10000 THEN 'Salary is greater than 10000'
WHEN SALARY<10000 THEN 'Salary is less than 10000'
ELSE 'Salary is equal to 10000'
END AS 'SALARY STATEMENT'
FROM hr.employees;
```

This query gives me the output as:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Can anyone explain what's wrong?

Comment: just get rid of single quotes wrapping alias `'SALARY STATEMENT'` so as to make it `SALARY_STATEMENT`  or `"SALARY STATEMENT"`

Comment: Use `"SALARY STATEMENT"`, in double quotes, as the alias for the `CASE` expression.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Done that, could you also explain why double quotes are required here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle database object names, when escaped, should appear inside *double* quotes, not single quotes.  Single quotes denote string literals, not aliases.  The following version should work:

```sql
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,
       CASE WHEN SALARY > 10000 THEN 'Salary is greater than 10000'
            WHEN SALARY < 10000 THEN 'Salary is less than 10000'
            ELSE 'Salary is equal to 10000'
       END AS "SALARY STATEMENT"
FROM hr.employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the perfect answer. But in oracle you can also use decode.

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,
DECODE(SIGN(SALARY-10000),1, 'Salary is greater than 10000',-1, 'Salary is less than 10000', 'Salary is equal to 10000')
FROM hr.employees;
```